# C programming tool to replace variables by values in source

Tags: c, perl, gdb

I often debug numerical routines in C. This means I run the program with gdb and step into the function to be debugged. Then I compare numerical values with my expectations by printing the variables with gdb. Obviously this procedure is tedious for longer routines. In particular I need to remember the values of the different variables between subsequent runs if I change the routine and want to compare with previous results. In some cases it would help a lot (especially if the routine is more or less linear) if I had a tool which automatically replaces the variables by their numeric values encountered during execution. E.g. a short (trivial) example routine

```
myfunc(double a, double b)
{
  double tmp_a, tmp_b, c;

  tmp_a = a*a;
  tmp_b = b*b;

  c = sqrt(tmp_a+tmp_b);

  return c;
}
```

could be converted to

```
myfunc(double a<1.0>, double b<2.0>)
{
  double tmp_a, tmp_b, c;

  tmp_a = a<1.0>*a<1.0>;
  tmp_b = b<2.0>*b<2.0>;

  c = sqrt(tmp_a<1.0>+tmp_b<4.0>);

  return c<2.236067977499789696e+00>;
}
```

I could easily compare the output of subsequent runs using a diff tool. Also I could compare intermediate numerical results with arbitrary precision results by pasting the output into a computer algebra system. The rough idea is that a gdb driver executes the binary until the specified routine, executes it step by step (each time replacing all variables in a step by their respective values at that time) and finally exits. Hints to existing software or ideas for implementations are highly welcome. Maybe there is a solution based on perl using existing gdb interfaces such as `Devel::GDB` (not sure if this one is grown up enough).

---

It seems that since version 7 gdb has support for python scripts. A minimal example which loads a single threaded executable, sets a breakpoint, runes the executable and prints a variables value once the breakpoint is reached would be really helpful for me.

Comment: That is not a replacement, it's some kind of labelling. I don't know a tool to do this, but it would make more sense to use comments, i.e. `a/*1.0*/` since that would at least let the source build.

Comment: Well, in the ideal case this would be freely configurable. So I could have a true replacement as well (this would make it most easy to copy to a computer algebra system which supports C syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on optimization in your example and the arguments are constants in your code, I would expect the compiler does exactly that, and simplifies the whole thing to return a pre-calculated square root of 5.

There are products on the market that does "code flow analysis" and that understands boundary conditions and "it's an error if sqrt is called with a negative value" and that sort of thing. Coverity is a (not anywhere near free) tool that does this on C/C++, and spits out "You are trying to do something stupid here, are you sure this is right?" type messages for your code.

Valgrind can do similar things as well.

But neither of these tools can annotate the current values of the variables for a set of runs of the code. It would be possible to do, but it would be rather time-consuming compared to running the code at full speed, and if the code is anything more than a few hundred lines that run a few iterations, it would probably take almost forever and produce a very large log-file of what happened where. Not at all convinced it is practical.

Comment: The above example is a trivial one as I said. Compiler optimizations such as those you mention would be turned off using `-O0`. Note that I am NOT primarily talking about "sqrt(-1)" type of mistake (I would search these using the gnu floating point exceptions extension) or other mistakes which a debugger could spot automatically. Mainly I am interested in finite precision errors which do not necessarily lead to invalid operations. Errors of this type which appear after hundreds of iterations would still be more difficult to spot if I debug step by step.

Comment: And would be rather difficult to spot in a log of 10000 lines of output too. And I expect that there are only certain spots in the code that are particularly sensitive, so adding manual logging may be a better choice.

Comment: I am talking about routines which are order 1000 lines long. 10000 lines of output would not be a lot... With a graphical diff tool like kdiff3 (there are many others) I find it perfectly possible to see something.

Comment: Yes, and if you have 1000 lines that are iterated 10 times, you get 10000 lines. With 1000 iterations, you have a million lines. And you can only `diff` something if you have a template with "correct results". My point is that you get an awful lot of output, much of which is probably meaningless for what you are looking for.

Comment: I understand your point and agree that at some point it will become impracticable. After all I am writing the code in C because it needs to step through much more iterations than I can ever follow. But of course it can already be very helpful to compare the output of a single iteration which I could easily single out. The primary target is to make the individual iterations safe, right. I am sure that in certain cases (those I am talking about) this kind of output would be very useful. The questions is merely how to produce it ...

Answer (score 0):

you could go in a different way:
Create a log file (can by done with printf and redirect of the standerd output at the run). you can print the values of interest and `diff` two logs from different runs.

Comment: Sure I do print key variables for my code. But imagine a code which is way to long to do this by hand for every single one! My routines are of this sort. If I would even attempt it for a single one, I could come up with a first prototype for the outlined code in less time. And I would need to redo it after every single change in the code.